# Flow value over edges in Max flow/Min Cut Ford Fulkerson

Tags: ford-fulkerson

Is it true that if a given edge e is in the min cut of a graph that there exists a max flow of the graph that has e with its full capacity?

Comment: A cut is usually a *collection* of edges. Are you strictly interested in the restricted case where the cut is a single edge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. More precisely, for every min cut $(W,\bar{W})$, there is some max flow $f$ such that $f(x,y)=0$ if edge $(x,y)$ goes from $\bar{W}$ to $W$, and $f(x,y)$ equals the capacity of $(x,y)$ if edge $(x,y)$ goes from $W$ to $\bar{W}$. This is usually proven using the linear programming formulations of min cut and max flow, and follows by the [complementary slackness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming#Complementary_slackness) property.